Pickup specific request based on input from data file
I am having list of request under a collection.I want to run a particular request based on input which is being passed via data file.
For Example:
If name of requests will be TC-1,TC-2,TC-3,TC-4...I want to run only TC-2 and TC-3 based on inputs from my data file.I will keep my data file as csv format and will keep my all inputs in row(As mentioned in image]
Requests under Collection File
Data file
Can anyone provide a solution
Thanks in advance

This would be a great question to ask over on the Postman community fourm. It might receive a more specific answer on there.

It is possible only selected request from data file (environment JSON).
In the Pre-request-script tap, can skip request by this function.
pm.execution.skipRequest();

Also environment variables can assign only run items.
So  this logic can handle
const testCaseIDs = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('testCaseIDs'));
const requestName = pm.info.requestName;
let  isTest = false;

_.forEach(testCaseIDs, (testCaseID) => {
    if(requestName.includes(testCaseID)) {
        isTest = true;
    }
})

if (!isTest) {
    console.log(requestName + " Skip");
    pm.execution.skipRequest();
} else {
    console.log(requestName + " Ran");
}


Environment variable

Demo Collection
I want to run only TC-2 and TC-3 among 8 Requests
Request mane should be includes TC-[number]
It can flexible, like [TC-1],[TC-1] name, TC-1, TC-1 name possible.

Save as 1-demo.postman_collection.json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "2425762f-9acf-4ca9-b3e7-96a6be66ffea",
        "name": "1-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "2207020"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "[TC-1] Lion",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Lion\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const testCaseIDs = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('testCaseIDs'));\r",
                            "const requestName = pm.info.requestName;\r",
                            "let  isTest = false;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if(testCaseIDs) {\r",
                            "    _.forEach(testCaseIDs, (testCaseID) => {\r",
                            "        if(requestName.includes(testCaseID)) {\r",
                            "            isTest = true;\r",
                            "        }\r",
                            "    })\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!isTest) {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Skip\");\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Ran\");\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Lion",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Lion"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "[TC-2] Elephant",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Elephant\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const testCaseIDs = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('testCaseIDs'));\r",
                            "const requestName = pm.info.requestName;\r",
                            "let  isTest = false;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if(testCaseIDs) {\r",
                            "    _.forEach(testCaseIDs, (testCaseID) => {\r",
                            "        if(requestName.includes(testCaseID)) {\r",
                            "            isTest = true;\r",
                            "        }\r",
                            "    })\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!isTest) {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Skip\");\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Ran\");\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Elephant",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Elephant"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "TC-3 Tiger",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Tiger\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const testCaseIDs = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('testCaseIDs'));\r",
                            "const requestName = pm.info.requestName;\r",
                            "let  isTest = false;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if(testCaseIDs) {\r",
                            "    _.forEach(testCaseIDs, (testCaseID) => {\r",
                            "        if(requestName.includes(testCaseID)) {\r",
                            "            isTest = true;\r",
                            "        }\r",
                            "    })\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!isTest) {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Skip\");\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Ran\");\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Tiger",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Tiger"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "TC-4 Kangaroo",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Kangaroo\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const testCaseIDs = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('testCaseIDs'));\r",
                            "const requestName = pm.info.requestName;\r",
                            "let  isTest = false;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if(testCaseIDs) {\r",
                            "    _.forEach(testCaseIDs, (testCaseID) => {\r",
                            "        if(requestName.includes(testCaseID)) {\r",
                            "            isTest = true;\r",
                            "        }\r",
                            "    })\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!isTest) {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Skip\");\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Ran\");\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Kangaroo",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Kangaroo"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "TC-5 Gorilla",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Gorilla\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const testCaseIDs = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('testCaseIDs'));\r",
                            "const requestName = pm.info.requestName;\r",
                            "let  isTest = false;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if(testCaseIDs) {\r",
                            "    _.forEach(testCaseIDs, (testCaseID) => {\r",
                            "        if(requestName.includes(testCaseID)) {\r",
                            "            isTest = true;\r",
                            "        }\r",
                            "    })\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!isTest) {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Skip\");\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Ran\");\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Gorilla",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Gorilla"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "TC-6 Polar Bear",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Polar Bear\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const testCaseIDs = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('testCaseIDs'));\r",
                            "const requestName = pm.info.requestName;\r",
                            "let  isTest = false;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if(testCaseIDs) {\r",
                            "    _.forEach(testCaseIDs, (testCaseID) => {\r",
                            "        if(requestName.includes(testCaseID)) {\r",
                            "            isTest = true;\r",
                            "        }\r",
                            "    })\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!isTest) {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Skip\");\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Ran\");\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Polar%20Bear",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Polar%20Bear"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "TC-7",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Koala\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const testCaseIDs = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('testCaseIDs'));\r",
                            "const requestName = pm.info.requestName;\r",
                            "let  isTest = false;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if(testCaseIDs) {\r",
                            "    _.forEach(testCaseIDs, (testCaseID) => {\r",
                            "        if(requestName.includes(testCaseID)) {\r",
                            "            isTest = true;\r",
                            "        }\r",
                            "    })\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!isTest) {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Skip\");\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Ran\");\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Koala",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Koala"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "[TC-8]",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Giraffe\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const testCaseIDs = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('testCaseIDs'));\r",
                            "const requestName = pm.info.requestName;\r",
                            "let  isTest = false;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if(testCaseIDs) {\r",
                            "    _.forEach(testCaseIDs, (testCaseID) => {\r",
                            "        if(requestName.includes(testCaseID)) {\r",
                            "            isTest = true;\r",
                            "        }\r",
                            "    })\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!isTest) {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Skip\");\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(requestName + \" Ran\");\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Giraffe",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Giraffe"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "packages": {},
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "packages": {},
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Save as demo.postman_environment.json
{
    "id": "8fb2f4e2-18a1-4300-a93e-2b6e3f611fd7",
    "name": "demo",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "testCaseIDs",
            "value": "[\"TC-2\",\"TC-3\"]",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2024-04-18T18:06:11.388Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/10.24.22"
}

Run it by newman
From environment file
newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json -e demo.postman_environment.json

Result

From variable value
run only TC-2 and TC-5
newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json --env-var "testCaseIDs=[\"TC-2\",\"TC-5\"]"

Result


Note
I try it from CSV file directly but I did not success.


@QARR, can you me this answer up vote too? Thanks!
